# Filter association in search results using rails sunspot

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, solr, sunspot, sunspot-rails

I have this model

```rb
class Subject
  has_many: contents
  has_many: titles, :through => :contents

  searchable do
    text :titles, :default_boost => 5, :stored => true do
      my_titles = titles.map { |title| title.try(:name) }

      if my_titles.present?
        my_titles += titles.map do |title|
          title.path.map { |title| title.try(:name) }
        end
      end

      my_titles.flatten.uniq.join(" ")
    end
  end
end

class Title
  has_ancestry
end
```

When I'm searching for a subject it's working fine, but I need to add the feature to remove unnecessary Titles in my view. For example, when I search a Subject named "Human Biology", I get the result

```
Subject: Science 1
Titles: 
  - Environmental Science >> Human Biology # <-----this record need to stay
  - Chemistry 1 >> Chemistry 2 # <-----remove this
  - Physics 1 >> Physics 2 # <-----remove this

Subject: Science 2
Titles:
    Environmental Science >> Human Biology # <-----this record need to stay
    Chemistry 1 >> Chemistry 2 # <-----remove this
```

The Subjects appears in my search results, while I need to filter the titles based on what I searched for.

Here's my View:

```
<% @subjects.each_hit_with_result.each do |hit, subject| %>
  <% subject.titles.uniq.each do |title| %>
    <br/>
    <%=raw title.path.map {|e| link_to("#{e.name}", contents_url(:title => e.id) )}.join(' > ') %>
    <br/>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I tried to get the search params and use the select function, but I think this is not the right implementation.

Comment: Please take another pass at editing and try to improve the punctuation and capitalization. SO isn't a message board or forum, it's like an online reference book, where those things matter. Without it you make it harder for us to understand what you're asking. See "[ask]"
 and its linked pages, along with "[Is it OK to downvote questions because of bad grammar?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253780/128421)".

Comment: @theTinMan im very sorry in my grammar. but im trying to illustrate my question

Comment: The grammar is unrelated to your attempt to illustrate the question. I'd highly recommend using a grammar checker on the text of your question.

Comment: ill just add more illustration and wait for someone who can help me thanks. you already down vote my question how should i listen :)

Comment: How do you determine "unnecessary subject"? Do you only want to return the item that matches your query? Why do those other items give hits if they're not relevant to your query?

Comment: @MatsLindh i use hits because i will use highlight in the future

Comment: @MatsLindh i update my question

Comment: @DeezNuuts - I think you haven't properly followed the documentation of the Gem (https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot).

Please go through the documentation again It will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I guess [this](https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot#joins) will help you to do a correct search.

Something like this

```ruby
searchable do
  text :name
  join(:titles, target: Title, type: :text, join: { from: :subject_id, to: :id })
end
```